# Resolving merge conflicts through a pull request

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

I have **two branches**, `Master` which reflects `Production`, and a current release branch (let's call it `Sprint`) serving as base branch for all developers for the ongoing release. On both the branches, I have *permissions* setup that *no changes* will be *pushed directly* without a `Pull Request`.

Now, I need to merge `Master` into `Sprint` but when I do that, I've **merge conflicts**.

How can I *resolve* those conflicts since I can't push anything directly to `Sprint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can :

On your local repo :

- create a `workbranch` from master
- merge `Sprint` into `workbranch` (`git merge Sprint`)
- fix the conflicts (they will be the same as the ones in the pull request) and commit the result on `workbranch`
- push `workbranch` to your remote

On bitbucket :

- open a pull request to merge `workbranch` into `master`

Comment: At your last point - Shouldn't we create pull request to merge workbranch to sprint? Since workbranch is from master so it already has master's changes and we will simply push it to sprnt. Otherwise what is the point to create workbranch from master and push it back to master?

Comment: @PrateekGautam : the OP asked a question where both `master` and `Sprint` are protected, so he can't directly merge one into another.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue where I can push changes to any branch only through PR. There is conflict when I'm merging release branch into master. To your solution, I've created a separate branch from release branch and took pull from master and resolved the conflict. Now I'm confused to create pull request. Should I create PR from my_temp_branch to master or my_temp_branch to release? my_temp_branch originates from release branch.

Comment: @PrateekGautam : actually it's pretty symmetric : you have combined the changes from `master` and `release` (you technically *first* started from one branch *then* integrated the other, but the result is `master + release`). Just target the branch that needs to be updated (both of them if you need to)